# What need i to change my Responsive of my Website

Tags: css

What need i to change my Responsive of my Website
For viewing with Phone's: http://ekizcekoyu.com/ekizcekoyu/index.html
And link of my Responsive for the "Code's": http://ekizcekoyu.com/ekizcekoyu/css/responsive.css

I hope that anyone can help me with correct Code's so that i can update my Responsive..

Regards...

Comment: Welcome to SO, please look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: You can use Bootstrap, take a look at the bootstrap grid system. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Thank You.. oke i go read the ask a question :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter the css files and insert in them media queries, where for a specific screen size the css applied to the website is the one inside the query.

For exemple, for most smartphone you canuse this queries

```
@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
  /* CSS for screens that are 320 pixels or less will be put in this section */
}

@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:640px) {
  /* for screens that are at least 320 pixels wide but less than or equal to 640 pixels wide */
}
```

To test the website in a screen with this size you can use inspect element in chrome and use the device toolbar.

Im not sure if this answers your question, but hope it helps.

Comment: i did it and try it but now is my menu gone on screen of my phone is there too a code for menu toggle ?

Comment: I see it now i need help not only the screen min & max width but too with menu toggle

Comment: You need to adjust every element to the screen size, normally i prefer use something like: `width=100%` or `margin=2%`, that way the element adjusts to the screen size